# how to create dylibs that link to boost

Tags: c++, boost, makefile, osx-yosemite, dylib

I am using clang and boost 1.57 on OSX Yosemite. I am trying to create a dylib for a python application (used swig to make the wrappers). I have successfully compiled this code for Windows and Linux, so I know it is the build/link phase on OSX that is causing me issues. Here is my makefile (which is wrong, somehow):

```
CC=clang++

vpath %.c ./
vpath %.h ./

SRCS=RecorderLib.cpp RecorderLib_wrap.cpp
OBJS=$(SRCS:.cpp=.o)

LIBS= -lpython2.7 -lboost_iostreams-mt -lboost_system-mt -lboost_thread-mt -lboost_date_time-mt -lboost_chrono-mt -lboost\
_filesystem-mt -lboost_regex-mt -lboost_atomic-mt -lboost_serialization-mt -lboost_program_options-mt


CFLAGS=-arch x86_64 -Xarch_x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -pipe -O2 -c -stdlib=libstdc++
LINKFLAGS = -dynamiclib -undefined suppress -flat_namespace

.PHONY: RecorderLib64.dylib

all: RecorderLib_wrap.o RecorderLib.o RecorderLib64.dylib

RecorderLib_wrap.o:
        $(CC) RecorderLib_wrap.cpp $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o RecorderLib_wrap.o

RecorderLib.o:
        $(CC) RecorderLib.cpp $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o RecorderLib.o

RecorderLib64.dylib:
        $(CC) $(LINKFLAGS) $(OBJS) $(LIBS) \                                                                            
        -o RecorderLib64.dylib
        mv RecorderLib64.dylib ../../
clean:
        rm *.o
```

If I remove the `-undefined suppress -flat_namespace` flags, the thing will toss me a million `symbol not found for architecture x86_64` errors for all the boost functions that I reference.

When I include those flags, the library compiles but when I fire up the host application I get an error such as 
`OSError: dlopen(/Users/myself/RecorderApp/src/RecorderLib64.dylib, 6): Symbol not found: __ZN5boost9iostreams15file_descriptor4seekElSt12_Ios_Seekdir`

which I interpret to mean the dylib doesn't know about boost.

One other thing that I don't understand, but is possibly related, is that when I compile the source objects, it tosses me errors such as:
`clang: warning: -lpython2.7: 'linker' input unused`

On linux, you want to link to libraries both at the compile stage and the link stage (at least this is my understanding -- in any case my Makefile.gnu which I am basing this off of does this and works beautifully).

I should also mention that I can compile applications on this system that link to boost and various dylibs and they work perfectly, so I know my boost installation etc. is alright. Also, inspecting the libraries I link to with the `file` command tells me they are of the correct x86_64 architecture.

Later:
So, I realize now that the `symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64` errors were actually pointing to functions in the stdlib (but were referenced from boost), i.e.:

```
  "std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::setbuf(char*, long)", referenced from:
      vtable for boost::iostreams::stream_buffer<boost::iostreams::file_descriptor_sink, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>, boost::iostreams::output> in RecorderLib.o
```

Changing the makefile so that the min osx version is 10.7 and using `-stdlib=libc++` gets rid of all theses errors, but I am still getting `symbol(s) not found` for a boost:iostreams call:

```
  "boost::iostreams::file_descriptor::seek(long,std::__1::ios_base::seekdir)"
```

Comment: PS, I got my boost from homebrew. Do I really need to compile it myself with the --stdlib=libstdc++ flag? What a pain!